# Call Autohotkey script from Julia

Tags: julia, autohotkey

I am a beginner in Julia-lang, have broad knowledge in autohotkey.

I have this script, how can I call this from Julia?

```
T::
A::ExitApp 

MsgBox, Autonexus activated! Press "A" to terminate script.
Loop
{
PixelGetColor, Red, 696, 309 ; pixels
if Red = 0x545454
 {
Send, R
}
}
```

Could you show me simple example, so I can get to understand how to do it.

Comment: See: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs

Comment: Thx for trying but, that's not really what I am looking for. I am looking for examples of algorithm code.